# Error with socket. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'listen'

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to write a simple TCP socket server.

I'm getting this error:

```
  File "patch", line 9, in __init__
    self.__SocketServer__.listen(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'listen'
```

And I can't understand why.

Code:

```
class DataManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__port__ = 2121
        self.__ip__ = "127.0.0.1"
        self.__SocketServer__ = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.__SocketServer__ = self.__SocketServer__.bind((self.__ip__, self.__port__))
        self.__SocketServer__.listen(1)
        self.__log__("Waiting car connection...")
        self.__CarSocket__, addr = self.__SocketServer__.accept()
        self.__log__("Car socket connected")
        self.__CarSocket__ = None
```

Comment: Can I ask why you are using `__double_underscore__` names for *everything*? Python [reserves that class of names for its own uses](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, for private class members. Something wrong?

Comment: Private variables are done with `_single_underscore`s.

Comment: Yes, don't use `__name__` names for your own attributes. Just use `_name`, single underscore at the start. Python has no privacy model, only a *convention* of how to use names.

Comment: oh, sorry guys, i'm newbie in python, my main languages - is C++ and Java :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.bind()` returns `None`. Don't assign this back to your socket attribute:

```
self.__SocketServer__ = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
self.__SocketServer__.bind((self.__ip__, self.__port__))
self.__SocketServer__.listen(1)
```

On a side note: don't use `__doubleunderscore__` names for your own projects. Python [reserves this class of names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) for its own use.

If you want to mark names as internal to the instance, use single underscores at the start of names. Python classes have *no privacy model*, all attributes are always accessible from the outside.

So this suffices:

```
class DataManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self._port = 2121
        self._ip = "127.0.0.1"

        self._socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self._socket.bind((self._ip, self._port))
        self._socket.listen(1)

        self._log("Waiting car connection...")
        self._connection, addr = self._socket.accept()
        self._log("Car socket connected")
        self._connection = None
```

I've used more commonly-used names for the socket and connection, also adhering to the [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).